# How do you boot Puppy Linux Slacko into the command line?

Tags: boot, runlevel, puppy-linux

How do you boot Puppy Linux Slacko (or Precise or Wary) into the command line? I wish to `startx` only if I need it. Unfortunately it does not seem to copy Slackware's traditional `/etc/inittab` runlevel methodology.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Puppy Linux, but it should be possible to get a multiuser without X runlevel/target appending 3 to the kernel boot line. In any case, appending 1 or s should get singleuser (maintenance) level anyway. [This](http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=16307&sid=c9319030386560418cf49066c06e47f0) post seems to imply that starting X is done "by hand" in `/etc/profile`, check that one (read that file and possibly comment out the line)

Answer (score 1):

By appending `pfix=nox` to kernel options.

Answer (score 0):

`GNU/Linux` have 3 boot process: `SysV`, `upstart` and `systemd`, `SysV` have `inittab` and others don't use `inittab`. `debian` uses `SysV`, `Fedora` uses `systemd` and `ubuntu` uses `upsatrt`.

**Your answer:**

if you want to find out `puppy` which use boot process, see first paragraph of `init`.

**Note:**

if you know configuration of `inittab file`, indeed you know `upstart` and `systemd` configuration files. because they similar.

Comment: In Fedora at least (`systemd` now, was `upstart` until recently) the `/etc/inittab` file is used, but only to define default runlevel (even though `systemd` doesn't use runlevels' per se).

Comment: The two systems I am comfortable with inittab (in Slackware and Redhat Enterprise Linux) and Ubuntu (?upstart) are definitely NOT similar.

Comment: some of them i don't know which or both, if you ls, you can see inittab, but they just keep this file as traditional, not applicable.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh there's also [OpenRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenRC) used mostly by Gentoo.

Comment: Linux actually has far more init systems than just the three you're referencing.

Comment: @ChrisDown i didn't divide `init systems` into 3 section. i just explain poster doesn't search for inittab in each system.